# Как нарисовать треугольник зная три стороны и все углы

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно нарисовать треугольник у которого длина сторон и углы будут равны значениям, которые задал пользователь.Думал сделать через Graphics.DrawLine, но потом понял, что не совсем понимаю как это вообще должно реализовываться.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
            triangle.A = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            triangle.B = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            triangle.C = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;

            label4.Text = triangle.CalcPerimeter();
            label5.Text = triangle.CalcArea();

            double cosA = (Math.Pow(triangle.A, 2) + Math.Pow(triangle.C, 2) - Math.Pow(triangle.B, 2)) / (2 * triangle.A * triangle.C);
            double cosB = (Math.Pow(triangle.A, 2) + Math.Pow(triangle.B, 2) - Math.Pow(triangle.C, 2)) / (2 * triangle.A * triangle.B);
            double cosY = (Math.Pow(triangle.B, 2) + Math.Pow(triangle.C, 2) - Math.Pow(triangle.A, 2)) / (2 * triangle.C * triangle.B);
            double acosA = Math.Acos(cosA) * 180 / Math.PI;
            double acosB = Math.Acos(cosB) * 180 / Math.PI;
            double acosY = Math.Acos(cosY) * 180 / Math.PI;

            label6.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            label8.Visible = true;

            label6.Text = ("Cos(A)= " + acosA.ToString());
            label7.Text = ("Cos(B)= " + acosB.ToString());
            label8.Text = ("Cos(Y)= " + acosY.ToString());

            index = 1;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (index == 1) 
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine
            }
        }
```

Comment: Для построения треугольника по этим данным нужно зафиксировать точку (одну из вершин) и направление одной из сторон. Или шире, две точки, которые определяют прямую на которой лежит сторона треугольника и полуплоскость в которой лежит третья вершина.

Comment: Нарисуйте одну сторону, остальные две прилепите в соответствии с данными вам углами